# Can't integrate simple normal distribution in sympy, depending on mean and deviation constants

Tags: python, sympy

So... I can `sympy.integrate` a normal distribution with mean and standard deviation:

```
    (10.1, 0.333333333),  # Works fine
```

but not:

```
    (8.655555555555557, 0.5212875796916135), # Fails
```

Kinds feels like that shouldn't make a big difference.
What's up with that?

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import sympy
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import plot

def normal(x, mean, sigma):
    z = (x - mean) / sigma
    return (1 / (sigma * sympy.sqrt(2 * sympy.pi))) * sympy.exp(-(z * z) / 2)


for μ,σ in [
    (10.1, 0.333333333),  # Works fine
    (8.655555555555557, 0.5212875796916135), # Fails
]:
    x = symbols("x")

    print(f"μ={μ}, σ={σ}")
    distrib = normal(x=x,mean=μ,sigma=σ)
    # distrib = sympy.simplify(distrib) # Doesn't help
    distrib_cum = sympy.integrate(distrib, x)
    # distrib_cum = sympy.simplify(distrib_cum) # Doesn't help
    print(distrib_cum)
    plot(distrib_cum)
```

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-18-e85bdeabeaa6> in <module>
     22     # distrib_cum = sympy.simplify(distrib_cum) # Doesn't help
     23     print(distrib_cum)
---> 24     plot(distrib_cum)
     25 
     26 

~/venv/p37_default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in plot(show, *args, **kwargs)
   1738     plots = Plot(*series, **kwargs)
   1739     if show:
-> 1740         plots.show()
   1741     return plots
   1742 

~/venv/p37_default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in show(self)
    220             self._backend.close()
    221         self._backend = self.backend(self)
--> 222         self._backend.show()
    223 
    224     def save(self, path):

~/venv/p37_default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in show(self)
   1414 
   1415     def show(self):
-> 1416         self.process_series()
   1417         #TODO after fixing https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1255
   1418         # you can uncomment the next line and remove the pyplot.show() call

~/venv/p37_default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in process_series(self)
   1411             if isinstance(self.parent, PlotGrid):
   1412                 parent = self.parent.args[i]
-> 1413             self._process_series(series, ax, parent)
   1414 
   1415     def show(self):

~/venv/p37_default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in _process_series(self, series, ax, parent)
   1239             # Create the collections
   1240             if s.is_2Dline:
-> 1241                 collection = self.LineCollection(s.get_segments())
   1242                 ax.add_collection(collection)
   1243             elif s.is_contour:

~/venv/p37_default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in get_segments(self)
    704                     list_segments.append([p, q])
    705 
--> 706             f_start = f(self.start)
    707             f_end = f(self.end)
    708             sample(np.array([self.start, f_start]),

~/venv/p37_default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py in __call__(self, args)
    173         try:
    174             #The result can be sympy.Float. Hence wrap it with complex type.
--> 175             result = complex(self.lambda_func(args))
    176             if abs(result.imag) > 1e-7 * abs(result):
    177                 return None

~/venv/p37_default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    270 
    271     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 272         return self.lambda_func(*args, **kwargs)
    273 
    274 

<string> in <lambda>(x0)

NameError: name 'Integral' is not defined
```

The first problem:

```
μ=10.1, σ=0.333333333
0.353553390593274*sqrt(2)*erf(2.12132034568096*x - 21.4253354913777)
```

works fine.

The second:

```
μ=8.655555555555557, σ=0.5212875796916135
1.30203374788369e-60*sqrt(2)*Integral(exp(31.8522556903367*x)*exp(-1.83998909636091*x**2), x)/sqrt(pi)
```

fails with 'NameError: name 'Integral' is not defined' when plotted.

(And I'm a little suspicious about whether `1.30203374788369e-60* ....` is going to end well).

Fails with the latest pip install as of today (python 3.7, sympy 1.18).

My mistake or a limitation of sympy?

Comment: I think u didn't import Integral from sympy in the second part

Comment: Yeah, but why the difference between the two cases? They're the same function, just different constants.

Comment: I wonder if `print(distrib)` sheds any light on the differences.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes -- I already included the output. Why two different function forms with minor differences in constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Don't use floats when it can be avoided. Python's finite precision does not play well with SymPy's infinite precision algorithms.

This is very similar to the `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004` story.

For both cases, SymPy eventually tries the Meijer G algorithm to evaluate the integral. After it has automatically removed a coefficient, it tries to integrate the expression.

So for the first example it tries to integrate `exp(-459.04500091809*(0.099009900990099*x - 1)**2)` with the substitution `y = x + 10.1000000000000`. This results in `exp(-4.500000009*x**2)` which Meijer can solve.

However, for the second example, it tries to integrate `exp(-137.849484348735*(0.115532734274711*x - 1)**2)` with the substitution `y = x + 8.65555555555556`. This results in `exp(-1.83998909636091*(x - 9.60959706869997e-16)**2)` which Meijer cannot solve because it does not have that typical form of `exp(-x^2)`.

There are 3 ways to solve the problem:

1. Use something that is infinite precision such as rationals. Depending on the type of calculation and the number of trial values, this or option 2 could be the most efficient:

```py
import sympy
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import plot

def normal(x, mean, sigma):
    z = (x - mean) / sigma
    return (1 / (sigma * sympy.sqrt(2 * sympy.pi))) * sympy.exp(-(z * z) / 2)

x = symbols("x")

for μ, σ in [
    (sympy.Rational("10.1"), sympy.Rational(1, 3)),  # Works fine
    (sympy.Rational("8.655555555555557").limit_denominator(10**10), 
     sympy.Rational("0.5212875796916135").limit_denominator(10**10)), # Fails
]:
    print(f"μ={μ}, σ={σ}")
    distrib = normal(x, μ, σ)
    distrib_cum = sympy.integrate(distrib, x)
    
    print(distrib_cum)
    plot(distrib_cum)
```

2. Compute it once and then substitute the test values. Some cases might need to you to specify some symbols as real or positive.

```py
import sympy
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import plot

def normal(x, mean, sigma):
    z = (x - mean) / sigma
    return (1 / (sigma * sympy.sqrt(2 * sympy.pi))) * sympy.exp(-(z * z) / 2)

x, mu, sigma = symbols("x, mu, sigma")

distrib = normal(x, mu, sigma)
distrib_cum = sympy.integrate(distrib, x)

for μ, σ in [
    (10.1, 0.333333333),  # Works fine
    (8.655555555555557, 0.5212875796916135), # Fails
]:
    print(f"μ={μ}, σ={σ}")
    print(distrib_cum.subs({mu: μ, sigma: σ}))
    plot(distrib_cum.subs({mu: μ, sigma: σ}))
```

3. Maybe SymPy has it already calculated for you. Of course this is the cdf and not the antiderivative of the pdf. There is a subtle difference of a constant.

```py
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import plot
from sympy.stats import Normal, cdf

x = symbols('x')

for μ, σ in [
    (10.1, 0.333333333),  # Works fine
    (8.655555555555557, 0.5212875796916135), # Fails
]:
    print(f"μ={μ}, σ={σ}")
    distrib_cum = cdf(Normal('X', μ, σ))(x)
    print(distrib_cum)
    plot(distrib_cum)
```

Comment: For future reference and for anyone who considers this a bug and believes it can be fixed, the main focus would be around line 1661 of `sympy/integrals/meijerint.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a close case that works:

```
In [125]: normal(x, 8.6, 0.5)
Out[125]: 
                                         2
        -147.92⋅(0.116279069767442⋅x - 1) 
1.0⋅√2⋅ℯ                                  
──────────────────────────────────────────
                    √π                    

In [126]: integrate(_,x)
Out[126]: 0.353553390593274⋅√2⋅erf(1.41421356237309⋅x - 12.1622366364086)
```

And the one that doesn't:

```
In [127]: normal(x, 8.655555555555557, 0.5212875796916135)
Out[127]: 
                                                                2
                     -137.849484348735⋅(0.115532734274711⋅x - 1) 
0.95916346270094⋅√2⋅ℯ                                            
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                √π                               

In [128]: integrate(_,x)
Out[128]: 
                        ⌠                                             
                        ⎮                                         2   
                        ⎮  31.8522556903367⋅x  -1.83998909636091⋅x    
1.30203374788369e-60⋅√2⋅⎮ ℯ                  ⋅ℯ                     dx
                        ⌡                                             
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                  √π
```

I don't know why there's a difference.  Sometimes in `sympy` cases we need to add constraints to symbols, such as `real` or `positive`.  Looks like it's failing to reduce the integral to `erf`.  I wonder if there are ranges of values for which the `erf` definition is valid.  I haven't worked with that in years.

As you note that leading `1.30203374788369e-60` is suspicious, especially compared to 1 in the working case.

Lopping off a couple of digits from the sigma makes it work: `0.52128757969161`

Comment: Thanks - although the point of symbolic math is that we can deal with exact computation, no? And also this process seems a little random about when it works and when it does not.

Comment: I believe integration involves a lot of heuristics.  It's been a long time since I took calculus.  Not everything thing has an anti-derivative.  See `integrate's` docs.  Even `erf` is defined as an integral (`2/sqrt(pi)*integral(exp(-t**2)`) with a numeric approximation found in Abramowitz (that takes me back to undergrad days!).